# command line alias inside php exec

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, fastcgi, alias

Is there any possibility to define shell alias for commands executed via php `system`, `exec` etc functions?
I'm running multiple versions of PHP using fastcgi and I need to run the right version of PHP when I execute

```
exec('php -f script.php');
```

inside web application, so for some vhosts calling `php` I need to run `/usr/bin/php` and for others e.g. `/opt/php5.2.4/bin/php`.

My virtual vhost configuration looks like this

```
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
        Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
        Alias /php5-fcgi /var/www/test.loc/www.test.loc/cgi-bin/php52.fcgi
    </IfModule>
```

And `php52.fcgi` (php55.fcgi respectively):

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=200
export PHPRC="/opt/php5.2.4/php.ini"
exec /opt/php5.2.4/bin/php-cgi
```

So every vhosts has it's own php5x.fcgi script and php.ini file.